Auto-filling the "To" value to the selected related record

On Salesforce side panel, search for a person account record, click Log on the person account records

In Other section, leave it as it is by selecting the record. Then click Save button in Salesforce side panel. Email-To-Salesforce UI looks like below


﻿﻿
Expectation is the email of the related person contact should be auto populated in to address.
Is that something configurable ?
